# Is there a document for cordova as a node module?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

Most document is for command line, not for module.
I want to use cordova in my nodejs.
Anyone help?

I use it like below:

```
var cordova = require('cordova');
cordova.platform("add", "android");
……
```

Comment: Rly unfortunate there's no documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No document.
You should use:

```
var cordova = require('cordova-lib');
```

not:

```
var cordova = require('cordova');
```

.
If you want to know how to use cordova-lib as a node.js module, you should look the source code at **cordova-lib/src/cordova**.

Answer (score 0):

You can realize it with [child processes](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) in node.js. Create a JavaScript file `myJsFileToRun.js` in your root project folder and add for your example into it:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child;

var command = "cordova platform add android";

child = exec( command, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

In your shell start your script with `node myJsFileToRun.js`

Comment: I really know I can do it like this, but I don't think it's a good idea. any document for cordova as node module.